# Drivers in 2in1

Tags: wireless, sound, xubuntu, bluetooth, touchscreen

I’m using xubuntu in a generic 2in1: http://www.kanjitech.com/tablets/hana/

I’ve problems to use Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, sound, touchscreen, screen rotation, nothing is working.

I think that this images and outputs it can help you to help me: BIOS IMAGES:

[image]

```
user@user:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1017:1006 Speedy Industrial Supplies, Pte., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

user@user:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 2280 (rev 22)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b0 (rev 22)
00:03.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b8 (rev 22)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 22dc (rev 22)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b5 (rev 22)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Device 2298 (rev 22)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 229c (rev 22)
```